# Why can I call a functional expression before it's defined?

Tags: javascript

In the example below, I can call the functional expression **b** from the functional expression **a** even though b() is not defined at that point. Could you explain why this works?

Thanks in advance!

```js
function go() {
  const a = () => {
    b();
  }
  const b = () => {
    console.log("abc")
  }
  a();
}
go();
```

Comment: I admit I have been confused by why this is permitted, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been defined by the time the `a` function runs. `a()` is below `const b =`, so `b` has been defined.

But it wouldn't work if `b` was defined after

```js
function go() {
  const a = () => {
    b();
  }
  a();
  const b = () => {
    console.log("abc")
  }
}
go();
```

It's OK for a function body to reference something that hasn't been defined yet. But it's not OK for that function to **run** before the variable has been defined.

Comment: So the answer was in the question. The question was wrong. They are not calling a function before declaring/defining it.